# How to count the total unique numbers in this set?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

If we have the following set:

$\Big\{ \frac{1}{1},\frac{2}{1},...,\frac{k}{1},\frac{1}{2},...,\frac{k}{2},...,\frac{1}{k},...,\frac{k}{k} \Big\}$

it is very clear that there are some doublets of numbers, such as $\frac{1}{2}=\frac{2}{4}$. My question is, how do I compute the total number of unique numbers in this set? Is there any theorem or formula I could potentially use? I started to enumerate all the possibilities as:

$1,2,...,k,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},...,\frac{1}{k},\frac{3}{2},\frac{5}{2},\frac{7}{2},...$

but it just seems way too tedious.

Comment: Instead of asking for "counting the total unique numbers in this set" you could have asked for the cardinality of the set.

Answer (score 2):

This is [OEIS A018805](https://oeis.org/A018805). A formula is given there:
$$f(k)=\left(2\sum_{j=1}^k\varphi(j)\right)-1$$
where $\varphi$ is the totient function.

Comment: Thank you so much!